# Flexbox layout does not work in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10, flexbox

http://jsfiddle.net/J8rL7/87/

According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

It should work for IE10 with vendor-prefix.

But it does not!

UPDATE: And I just checked in latest Firefox it looks totally broken.

Why?

```
<div id="wrapper" style="margin:auto;background-color:yellow;height:100%;">
    <div style="width:50px;height:100%;">
        <div class="fluid-column" style="height:80%;background-color:green;">
            <div class="box" style="background-color:#ff99cc;height:25%;">1</div>
            <div class="box" style="background-color:#ff33cc;height:50%;">2</div>
            <div class="box" style="background-color:#ff66cc;height:25%;">3</div> 
        </div>   
        <div class="fix-column" style="height:20%;background-color:violet">
            <div class="box" style="background-color:orange;height:50%;">Total</div>
            <div class="box" style="background-color:blue;height:50%;">Test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

div{
    text-align:center;
   }

.box
{
    display:-webkit-box;-webkit-box-pack:center;-webkit-box-align:center;
    display:-ms-box;-ms-box-pack:center;-ms-box-align:center;
    display:-moz-box;-moz-box-pack:center;-moz-box-align:center;
}
```

Comment: It looks the same for me in IE10, Chrome, and Safari. What is it supposed to look like? Could you add an image mock-up of how it should appear, or a detailed description of the layout you're trying to achieve?

Comment: isn't it supposed to be `-ms-flex-pack, -ms-flex-align`?

Comment: @MattCoughlin In Chrome the text is vertically aligned. But not in FF and IE10 and -ms-box-align:center should vertically align it when -ms-box-orientation:vertically is used. I just forgot to copy/paste it... but it does not work with it neither.

Comment: Vertically aligned what?  Center?  Top?  Bottom?

Comment: See .box class its vertically centered.

Comment: I have same trouble with my firefox 21, it is suppose to work and it doesn't.

DId you give up the old way with a stick inside each box ? `<span></span>` http://jsfiddle.net/D9gnP/6/show :)

Comment: nah I did not give up just trying different things :) I am also just thinking about creating my chart/diagramm with a table and not div-inline-blocks or float... as a chart/diagramm is actually tabular data...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read the notes very closely on caniuse.  "Partial support" refers to supporting one of two older drafts, and they don't make a note of which browser supports which draft.  IE10 supports the [March 2012 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/), and it's the only one that's known to do so.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/ApHEy

```
.box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* fix for old FF */
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: ok then exchange IE10 (which works now) with FF21 because that one is broken: http://jsfiddle.net/J8rL7/98/ Is this a bug?

Comment: The "latest" Firefox still uses its antiquated 2009 implementation that's full of bugs.  I've added a fix.

Comment: Hey it even works for the latest safari 5.1.7 I am surprised.

Comment: btw. thanks for the codepen link did not know of it. Its page refreshing is way faster than jsfiddle thats great!

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox , you need to give a width to the elements you want to see stacking.

http://jsfiddle.net/J8rL7/101/

```
#wrapper div {width:100%;}
```