# HTML - Div to the bottom without absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Vkx9/).

I added some CSS for positioning the tab to the right.

I wanted those tabs to be in the bottom right of the container.

If I set the position of the div to absolute. That'll void the width of the tab content which in turn can be adjusted by setting the margin-right but that'll not be dynamic enough if the width of tab headers is greater than the margin-right defined.

Is there any alternative to push the tabs to the bottom right corner of the `tab-container`?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you allowed to modify html?

Comment: No.. I don't want to modify the HTML. I'm using javascript to set that tab position to be on top or at the bottom. So recreating with HTML will be a mess.

Comment: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/5Vkx9/1/) Check this and let me know

Answer (score 1):

When you can use modern css you may go for `flexbox`.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5Vkx9/2/

```
.tab-content
{
    flex: 8 1 auto;
}

.nav
{
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    order: 2;
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Here is the table of supported browsers: http://caniuse.com/flexbox as you can see IE10 is only partially supported and will need special attention: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17156937/3244925

Here is a good article on flexbox: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Loving flex more and more

Answer (score 0):

I've got an idea to add margin-top with javascript. It can be easily counted: `.tab-container` height - `.nav-tabs` height.

**FIDDLE:**
http://jsfiddle.net/5Vkx9/12/

Comment: I'll give it a try. This will help me I guess so.

Comment: Tell me if you need a help with a script.

Comment: The margin-top will need to be updated each time the size of `tab-container` change (means on every window resize at least). It looks like bad idea to me.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you want to achieve but is this what you want? Using `position: absolute;` and a bottom padding on the content pane.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Vkx9/3/**

[image]

Comment: Sorry that's not what I'm looking for.