# IE10's Flexbox : differences between March 2012 Draft and current frozen version

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10, flexbox

I found differences in the flexbox implementation of IE10 and Chrome/Firefox. According to first answer here : [Flexbox layout does not work in Internet Explorer 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156444/flexbox-layout-does-not-work-in-internet-explorer-10) IE10 is based of an older, working version of the Flexbox standard.

In practice, for me, I have to treat as bugs the differences between the IE10 implementation and others browsers more compliant to the frozen standards (pardon my too vague vocabulary).

Does somebody know about list compiling those difference, or about way to find them out ? Ideally I am also looking for know solutions/workaround.

The specific bug I face is that a flex element set to 100% uses 100% of its parents width, instead of using 100% of the available width. But I am at first looking for an elegant way to treat those flexbox implementation differences.

Many thanks

Olivvv

EDIT: What I am looking for, is to learn about IE10 specific flexbox implementation, which is different form the flexbox in chrome and FF (latest flexbox draft).

Comment: downvoter care to explain ? I suspect you did not understand the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those ressources are helpful at finding out what is the IE10 specific syntax for flex box. IE10 flexbox version is based on the march 2012 draft (http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772069(v=vs.85).aspx
http://zomigi.com/blog/flexbox-syntax-for-ie-10/

My question has been downvoted, I am curious to know why. When coding flexbox with IE10 as requirement, then the specific syntax for IE10 is relevant to know.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/codler/2148ba4ff096a19f08ea also useful in order to find the corresponding syntax

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Modernizr, then Modernizr 3 will have a new feature detection test called flexboxtweener that will detect this and allow you to include correct behavior when this condition is present, but as of right now you could do the test yourself, which is

```
Modernizr.addTest('flexboxtweener', testAllProps('flexAlign'));
```

See https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/812

Comment: Hi. thanks for answering. What I am to know is how IE10 flexbox works, not how to detect it. But I plussed your answer because it seems that "flexboxtweener" describe that particular implementation.

Comment: OK, thanks, but as written above "is how IE10 flexbox works, not how to detect it". (but well I see I confuse the verbs "am" and "want")