# Why doesn't css work in IE when it works as expected in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: css, html, web, forms

```
    input[type=text], input[type=password], select {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    input[type=submit] {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #808080;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    input[type=submit]:hover {
        background-color: #A9A9A9;
    }
    html,body {
      height:100%;
      width:100%;
      margin:0;
    }
    body {
      display:flex;
      background-color:#D3D3D3;
    }
    form {
      margin:auto;
    }
```

The above CSS code makes the form center aligned in Chrome and Firefox, but the same doesn't work in Internet Explorer. In IE, the form is center aligned horizontally, but not vertically. What is wrong and what can be done to make it align properly in IE as well?

Comment: Style must be inside head section

Comment: Why should style be inside head section?

Comment: Because it's a html convention https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

Comment: Okay, i have included it in head section. Still the css doesn't seem to get applied properly in IE? so any suggestions?

Comment: flex has only partial support in IE; it supports older syntax in ie10 and there is only partial support in ie11 due to a large number of bugs.. See http://caniuse.com/#search=flex  This is the most probable cause of your problem  Should be okay in edge though

Comment: Uninstall IE.. :D

Comment: vaibhav haha.....my team lead wanted me to fix it on IE aswell; anyways now i have it fixed; thanks to rachel gallen and cimmanon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above problem is because IE has only partial support for flex.

Including **align-items: center;** after **display: flex;**

made the css get properly applied in IE.

Thanks to Rachel Gallen for pointing it out to me that the problem was with flex support in IE.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17156937/5293838

Solution provided by cimmanon:

> You need to read the notes very closely on caniuse. "Partial support"
>   refers to supporting one of two older drafts, and they don't make a
>   note of which browser supports which draft. IE10 supports the March
>   2012 draft, and it's the only one that's known to do so.
>
> http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/ApHEy
>
> ```
>  .box {
>        display: -webkit-box;
>        display: -moz-box;
>        display: -ms-flexbox;
>        display: -webkit-flex;
>        display: flex;
>        -webkit-box-pack: center;
>        -moz-box-pack: center;
>       -ms-flex-pack: center;
>       -webkit-justify-content: center;
>       justify-content: center;
>       -webkit-box-align: center;
>        -moz-box-align: center;
>       -ms-flex-align: center;
>        -webkit-align-items: center;
>        align-items: center;
>        /* fix for old FF */
>        width: 100%;
>      }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for crediting me for pointing out the issue, but credit is also due to cimmanon [https://stackoverflow.com/users/1652962/cimmanon] , the user who wrote the answer you have referenced. Good call including the answer link but better still to insert the a quoted copy of the answer with reference

Comment: thanks, and yea sure i will also include the quoted copy of the answer :)